# How can "break our spirits" be translated into Spanish?

Tags: traducción

I want to translate "break our spirits" but I know the literal translation "romper nuestros espíritus" does not sound natural.

How could it be translated?

Comment: I had never heard that expression before. Bear in mind that this is a Spanish forum so some English expressions may be unknown for many of us. Could you provide an example of use, or a description of what it means in English?

Comment: Cuando te dejan con el ánimo por el piso, completamente abatido.

Comment: Suponte que alguien te dijera de todo y te deja destruido moralmente

Comment: they have to break our spirits.. making us re-live our worst nightmares

Comment: In Spanish we have the expression "partir algo el alma". Example: "ver a un perro abandonado me parte el alma".

Comment: Encontre una palabra, que tal "me destrozó el espíritu"

Comment: depende del contexto, en Mexico: Romper los ánimos, podria ser lo que buscas.

Comment: It's excatly what @CarlosAlejo has said. (In Spain)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puede ser traducida como "quebrantar nuestro espíritu" (sí, en singular pues se refiere a un grupo), "quebrantar nuestro ánimo".  Con un poco más de libertad, yo lo traduciría como "quebrantar nuestra determinación".  "They are trying to break our spirits" podría ser también traducido como "Están tratando de desmoralizarnos".

Comment: Llevo un rato pensando en la expresión, y esta era más o menos la conclusión a la que había llegado. Lo de "partir el alma" parece algo que puede suceder involuntariamente, como en el ejemplo que puse. La frase original parece algo más hecho a propósito.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo, estoy de acuerdo.  También, yo asocio "partir el alma" con un estado de tristeza o lástima, no necesariamente conllevante a la inácción, o desmoralizante.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a translation of "broken spirit", but you get the idea.

Salmos 51:17Reina-Valera 1960 (RVR1960)

17 Los sacrificios de Dios son el espíritu quebrantado;
Al corazón contrito y humillado no despreciarás tú, oh Dios.

"quebrantar nuestros espiritus" would be understood in many contexts, where Bible phrasing is commonly understood.